# Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam

I am following a CloudFormation tutorial and this is my AWS CloudFormation template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: A starter AWS Lambda function.
Resources:
  helloworldpython3:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: src/
      Description: A starter AWS Lambda function.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref Table
          REGION_NAME: !Ref AWS::Region
      Events:
        HelloWorldSAMAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref Table

Table:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
  Properties:
    PrimaryKey:
      Name: greeting
      Type: String
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

I can generate the final template with `aws cloudformation package`. But when I try to deploy it with `sam deploy`, I get this output from the shell:

> error : Waiting for changeset to be created..
> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: hello-world-sam,
> ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a
> terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched
> expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Invalid
> template property or properties [Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your YAML is not correctly formatted:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
Description: A starter AWS Lambda function.
Resources:
  helloworldpython3:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: src/
      Description: A starter AWS Lambda function.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref Table
          REGION_NAME: !Ref AWS::Region
      Events:
        HelloWorldSAMAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref Table
  Table:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
    Properties:
      PrimaryKey:
        Name: greeting
        Type: String
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

`Table` should be under the `Resources`. Use a linter like [cfn-python-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint)

Answer (score 7):

In my case cfn linter was ok with yaml, error (used aws CLI from cmd) was just

> Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state:
>
> For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED"

You should aways check [AWS console](http://console.aws.amazon.com) → CloudFormation → {stack_name} → Change Sets

My error reason here

> Status reason
>
> No updates are to be performed.

might help someone

Comment: This showed me the permissions error that had caused me to get this error message. Even though I had seen previous permissions errors at the command-line.