# Deploying AWS SAM 'Hello World' example. "Invalid outputs property" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am following the steps on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html) to deploy a serverless 'Hello World' application to AWS.

Everything is working as expected locally and validating my `template.yaml` file with `sam validate` is successful.

When following step 3 (Deployment to AWS), I get the following error:

`Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: my-app, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template format error: Invalid outputs property : [Type, Properties].`

This seems to indicate either:

- An error with the `Outputs` property of `template.yaml`. I thought this might be because `${ServerlessRestApi}` and `${AWS::Region}` need to be populated manually, but this doesn't seem to change anything
- An error with `Type` and `Properties` from `Resources` > `HelloWorldFunction`, but because this file is unchanged since it was generated by the CLI and the validator is successful, I don't know what the issue could be?

What is preventing my application from deploying? Is it an issue with `template.yaml` (below) or do I need to do something else?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  my-app

  Sample SAM Template for my-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - app.ts

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

The rookiest of errors, in case anyone else lands here:

Make sure you run `sam build` before you run `sam deploy --guided`.

Also per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117085/2627160) if you have any errors check CloudFormation and specifically the template for your change set, to make sure it matches what you're expecting.